# Map between $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $\Gamma(Y,f^{*}\mathcal{F})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am currently working with the pullback of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}$-modules. Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a continuous map of topological spaces and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$. Then the inverse image sheaf $f^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ is the sheaf on $Y$ associated to the presheaf $V\mapsto \lim\mathcal{F}(W)$ where $V$ is any open set in $Y$ and the direct limit is taken over all open subsets $W$ of $X$ such that $f(V)\subset W$.

We define $f^{*}\mathcal{F}$ to be the sheaf associated to the tensor product presheaf
$$V\mapsto (f^{-1}\mathcal{F})(V)\otimes_{(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X})(V)}\mathcal{O}_{Y}(V).$$

**Goal:** Whenever $f(V)\subset U$ for opens $V\subset Y$ and $U\subset X$ I want to construct a map $f^{*}:\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow (f^{*}\mathcal{F})(V)$, such that in particular we have a map between the global sections.

Note that when $f(V)\subset U$ for opens $V\subset Y$ and $U\subset X$ we do have a map 
$$\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow \lim \mathcal{F}(W), s\mapsto [(U,s)],$$
where the limit is again take over all open subset $W\subset X$ containing $f(V)$.

**Problem:** How can I find a map from $\lim \mathcal{F}(W)$ into $(f^{-1}\mathcal{F})(V)$?

For a map from $(f^{-1}\mathcal{F})(V)\rightarrow (f^{-1}\mathcal{F})(V)\otimes_{(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X})(V)}\mathcal{O}_{Y}(V)$ we can just send $r\mapsto r\otimes 1$.

**Last problem:** How does the map from $(f^{-1}\mathcal{F})(V)\otimes_{(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X})(V)}\mathcal{O}_{Y}(V)$ to $f^{*}\mathcal{F}(V)$ look like?

As one might have noticed all the maps that we still need have to deal with the sheafification, and I think that this is where my main struggle is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I believe you just need to realize that there is a canonical map $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}^a$ from a presheaf to its associated sheaf. You can use it for your two problems.

Comment: @Roland These are indeed the maps I need, but how are these maps defined?

Comment: Depending on your definition of the sheafification, it should be obvious. It may even be part of the sheafification. So what is your definition ?

Comment: @Roland This is the definition I use https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/007X. Now that I took a closer look I realise that the map for my first problem is just given by sending $[(U,s)]\mapsto \Pi_{x\in U} [(U,s)]$.  The second map is then given similarly.

Comment: Yes that's it. Note that in stack project (as in any other sources really), the canonical map $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}^a$ is immediately defined after the sheafification.